# ASP.NET/C# Error - passing value from drop down list via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to link two drop down lists using JQuery AJAX, but I'm not getting anything.

My ASP.NET code for the drop downs is:

```
<td><a href="#" title="Choose the park that you would like. Mandatory Field.">Park*</a></td><!-- PARK -->
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="parkDDL" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="ShowCurrentBuilding()" style="width:150px;" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem text="ALL" value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="Central" value="C"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="West" value="W"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="East" value="E"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>

<td><a href="#" title="Choose the building that you would like">Building</a>     </td><!-- BUILDING -->
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" ID="buildingDDL" runat="server" style="width:300px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="buildingToRoom"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

My code for the JQuery in between JS tags (As you can see, I'm not quite sure how to output what is returned to the drop down list):

```
function ShowCurrentBuilding() {
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",
url: "CreateRequest.aspx/GetCurrentBuilding",
data: '{name: ' + $('#<%= parkDDL.ClientID %> option:selected').val() + '}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: OnSuccess,
failure: function (response) {
alert(response.d);
}
});
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
alert(response.d);
}
```

I have also tried the following which i put in the document ready function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#<%=parkDDL.ClientID %>').on("change",function ShowCurrentBuilding() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "CreateRequest.aspx/GetCurrentBuilding",
                data: '{name: "' + $(this).find("option:selected").val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccessBuilding,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });

        function OnSuccessBuilding(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
```

});

Finally, here is my C# code:

```
namespace Team11
{
  public partial class CreateRequest : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {

//populate my initial drop down lists etc

}
}

//here is the function that is called in the JQuery function

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

    public string GetCurrentBuilding(string name)
    {
        string textbx = "";
        textbx = name;

        return textbx;


    }
```

I just want to filter the drop down list via ajax so the page doesn't reload with AutoPostBack = "true".

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure OnSelectedChanged is a specific server side .net event. If you want to execute a client side function, try onchange.

Comment: Put onchange instead of OnSelectedChanged. And did you put any breakpoints in this method: public static ArrayList GetCurrentBuilding(string name) ?

Comment: No, what kind of breakpoints would I put in? The function I have specified is at the bottom of my question. I haven't added anything else in. Thanks.

Comment: He was asking about breakpoints in the server side method, to see if it was being reached. In any case, did you try onchange?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it gets rid of the error, but how can I output it to the drop down list. I am returning an array list but I'm not sure how to show it in the drop down list. Also, I'm not even sure how to test whether I'm even getting the list since I don't how to output the ArrayList.

Comment: Sounds like different questions you have. You can indicate this question is answered, and ask new questions. You can do some research into seeing how to make and handle AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use the client side function, onchange, instead of server side, OnSelectedIndexChanged.